# What is the name of this inheritance design pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Instead of having a public virtual method, you have a public sealed method that calls a protected virtual method. Something like this:

```
public class Test {

    public void DoStuff(){
        // Do stuff here...
        ProtectedDoStuff();
        // Do more stuff...
    }

    protected virtual void ProtectedDoStuff(){
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
public class Test {

    public virtual void DoStuff(){
        // Do stuff here...
        // Do a lot of stuff...
        // Do more stuff...
    }
}

public class Test2 : Test {

    public override void DoStuff(){
        // Do same stuff as base
        // Do different stuff
        // Do more stuff just like base
    }
}
```

This avoid having to re-implement all the functionality from the public method if it will be needed all time.
I know this has already been asked on stackoverflow but I can't find the question.

Comment: This is called the ["Template method pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is template method pattern. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

> The template method pattern is a behavioral design pattern that defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in a method, called template method, which defers some steps to subclasses. It lets one redefine certain steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's structure.